# linq Expression.Coalesce and case insensitive in the same query

Tags: linq

My goal is simple: 
I need to create dynamic query (with entity framework and sql), and I need:
- avoid error with null rows in my table (string type)
- use case insensitive in the query

I can use case insensitive with this:

```
MethodInfo toLowerExpr = typeof(String).GetMethod("ToLower", Type.EmptyTypes);
var singleExpr2 = Expression.Call(propertyReference, toLowerExpr);
```

and I can avoid null exceptions with this:

```
Expression.Coalesce(propertyReference, Expression.Constant(string.Empty));
```

My goal now, is search with case insenstive, and avoid the null exceptions. But, if I mix both options I obtain this:

```
MethodInfo toLowerExpr = typeof(String).GetMethod("ToLower", Type.EmptyTypes);
var singleExpr2 = Expression.Call(propertyReference, toLowerExpr);
var propReference = Expression.Coalesce(singleExpr2, Expression.Constant(string.Empty));

{(p.Phone.ToLower() ?? "").Contains("678")}
```

This result is working with case insensitive, but not avoid the null exceptions :(

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve what you want:

```
(p.Phone ?? "").ToLower()
```

You need to reverse the order in which you combine your expression.

```
MethodInfo toLowerExpr = typeof(String).GetMethod("ToLower", Type.EmptyTypes);
// This will give you (p.Phone ?? "")
var coalescedProperty = Expression.Coalesce(propertyReference, Expression.Constant(string.Empty)); 
// And then call ToLower of the resulting expression
var propReference = Expression.Call(coalescedProperty , toLowerExpr);
```